# Why is storage not persisting?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am having a simple problem where I set some test data to local storage after an event listener event.

```
    <script>
                document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].setAttribute("action", "https://www.google.com/");

                document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit',
                function(){
                    alert("Test");
                    localStorage.setItem("persondetails","person");

                });

    </script>
```

My problem is:

It adds the dat to session storage on the page that I am currently on but when I navigate to a new page it does not persist.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861357/sessionstorage-is-gone-when-browser-is-refreshed-javascript Try LocalStorage

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I see mistake now, trying with local storage doesn't work either :(

Comment: Your code above doesn't use `localStorage` for anything useful, you set  `persondetails` to `person`, and then you read the value at `persondetails` and do nothing with it.  What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: @Keith I want to set "persondetails" to local storage so that it persists to the next page.

Comment: So where is the code that's reading this in the next page?.  ps. If your using say Chrome, you can see what's been placed into localeStorage, in debugger under Application tab, select your website do you see a `persondetails` key?

Comment: @Keith When I check it in the chrome inspect element, data is not present in local storage

Comment: "Obviously" localStorage will be available under the same domain where you set it. If you navigate to google.com, you won't see your item set

Answer (score 4):

What you miss is what SessionStorage is. From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage
>   object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to
>   localStorage; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage
>   has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared
>   when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the
>   browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a
>   page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated
>   with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from
>   how session cookies work.

Consider using `localStorage` instead. It will persist on new tabs and reloads

Comment: thanks for help! I tried with local storafge there and it does not persist on next page see edit